# Unable to get the output upon using textLabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, ios14

I am trying to get an output using the textLabel attribute in swift but xcode shows me a warning that textLabel, detailTextLabel, and imageView are deprecated in iOS 14 instead use UIListContentConfiguration, but upon using it am not getting the output.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier , for: indexPath)
//        cell.textLabel?.text = "This is a cell"
//        return cell
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            content.text = "This is a cell"
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
           
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            cell.textLabel?.text = "This is a cell"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

This is how I wrote the code to use the contentConfiguration but it's not working can anyone help me with it. I am not getting the value present in my cell as output.

Comment: Quick test, and it works fine for me. What is `K.cellIdentifier`? Did you register the cell in `viewDidLoad()`? Or did you give a cell prototype the identifier in Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If i am guessing right, you want to assign a text to cell's label. If so, create UILabel in your custom cell

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourCustomLabel: UILabel!
```

and instead of

```
cell.textLabel?.text
```

use

```
cell.yourCustomLabel.text
```

and assign it this way